# How to define a bean from a dependency class as @Primary in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Kafka Consumer and I'm implementing it using the Spring Cloud Stream Source.class binding and InboundChannelAdapter. This Source.class defines 3 MessageChannel beans: output, nullChannel, and errorChannel. My code looks like this:

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@Import(KafkaSourceConfig.class)
public class KafkaSource {

    @Autowired
    MessageChannel controlBusChannel;

    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1"), autoStartup = "false")
    public AgentActivityNoteCreated consumeAndSendMessage() {
          // UNIMPORTANT CODE
    }
}
```

I want to autowire in the output channel so that I can use it to start and stop my InboundChannelAdapter manually, but I'm getting this error when trying to autowire.

```
Field controlBusChannel in com.company.KafkaSource required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - output: defined by method 'output' in null
    - nullChannel: defined in null
    - errorChannel: defined in null
Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I understand the error, the app doesnt know which of the 3 beans to inject, but don't know how to mark the output channel as Primary since I didn't actually make the bean. How do I do that?

Comment: can you add the source code for Source.class?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd It's a spring cloud stream class https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/messaging/Source.java

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to use it https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.RELEASE/reference/html/_getting_started.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Bean definition is not present in your code. Then, following should work:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("output")
MessageChannel controlBusChannel;
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

Comment: Just for completeness, `MessageChannel output;` would not need a qualifier - spring will look for a bean name that matches the field name before giving up.